# Can I format one listBox to show some columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli

I use SQLite3 to read data from a database and then display the results in a `listBox`, I would to ask if there is possibility to display the results in a `listBox` as columns in nice show without using DataGrid.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: This will give you complete [multi column list box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/multicolumnlistbox.aspx).

Comment: @Adban is this C# or C++/CLI ?

Comment: @DavidePiras: C++ CLI and no problem with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use ListView instead of listBox.
Also you can still use [listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn.aspx) for multicolumn purpose

Answer (score 0):

Listbox is not designed to work with multiple columns. Any reason why you do not want to use a DataGrid?

In general a grid control is the most appropriate when dealing with items or records having multiple properties or fields to be shown in different columns, some people also use a ListView with the report/details style and several sub items one per each column.

In my experience when the final result is really a table/grid it is easier and simpler to use a grid instead of "forcing" a ListView to behave like a grid. ListView is not designed for that even if it can be used in a similar way.